# ATtiny84A programming without shield

Tags: attiny

I am thinking about buying an ATtiny84A, which fits perfectly into my project. I want to embed it into a watch that I am designing right now. But I want to buy an SMT version so I have less space to consume. What do I need for programming it through USB? Special Atmel chip? Or just 2 digital pins from USB directly into it? Thank you very much. :)

Comment: A USB programmer.

Comment: That is too bulky to fit into my project. And I can't find any chip that programmer which would tell me what I need.

Comment: You don't fit it into your project. There should be no reason to program it in the field.

Comment: What about software updates. Like bug fixes and stuff.

Comment: That's the end user's problem.

Comment: What the actual hell... Okay thanks for your time gotta find this online

Comment: *gotta find this online* is the right starting point before visiting this site.

Comment: I was searching for this for like 2 weeks. This is my final destination. It's better to be quiet than writing this to me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for that. Two weeks?

Comment: I am studying electronics at high school and my knowledge is limited. Yes I've been searching for a lot of time 2 hours a day but it's starting to be boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design your device to permit In Circuit Serial Programming - ISP.  This will let you continue to refine the program once the chip is in the circuit, and it will also be your primary method of programming *and testing* small production quantities.

Basically this means that the ISP and reset pins of your processor need to be able to be externally contacted - either by a header, pads for "pogo pin" spring contacts, an SOIC test clip, or perhaps micrograbbers hooked onto individual pins.

It also means that anything connected to those pins needs to not interfere with or be harmed by the programming process.  That particularly means that anything which could drive any of these pin needs to *not* do so while the MCU is being programmed, nor load them, nor get lastingly confused by operations the programmer does on them.

You'll also need an ISP programmer.  Proper ones are sold, but beware of cheap clones and marginal designs as these often give users plenty of trouble.  Fortunately, you can use an everyday Arduino running the ISP sketch to program ATtiny chips.  Do beware though, that if your target is powered at 3.3v it is *not safe* to use a programmer with 5v signals on it - you might get away with it a few times, but eventually it will cause issues.  So if you want to use an Arduino to ISP a lower voltage target, you either need an Arduino that runs at 3.3v, or to implement level shifting.

Do spend some effort to verify that you have the software support resources you may need for the ATtiny84A - it's one of the less common chips so it won't have the same degree of community support.

A further possibility is to use ISP to put a serial (or other) bootloader into the chip and then rely on that, however this won't cover all eventualities - if you discover you need to change the fuses, you'll need ISP for that, as it's something a bootloader can't do.

Comment: Not aceptable. It require making a hole in the watch, which render it not waterproof. And mounting a connector in a existent case is not an easy task. He can make a conventional prototype on a small perforboard with a wrist band for field testing and have access to all internal signal also. It will look nerd, but ...

Comment: On the contrary, nothing short of reprogrammability is remotely acceptable - no actual product has just one prototype, there's a whole pilot run that needs to be iteratively fixed. It's almost certain this improvised "watch" won't have a waterproof case, but even if it does, the connections can be inside. In the real world, people engineer systems to be able to finish them. Or to exercise the trite meme, the 1990's called and they want their OTP MCU's back.  Why would you return there by choice?  Today, even throwaway products often have ISP/SWD pads - because their designers aren't idiots.

Comment: For god's Sake! He is a high school student! He need a cheap, easy, affordable solution. Even a US$70 solution is too expensive for him. He probably only have access to a solder iron and a multimeter. You are giving the right answer to the wrong person. Focus on people and his needs.

Comment: You seem to have neither any idea of what you are talking about, nor any reading comprehension - as already explained above ISP requires only a cheap Arduino clone for support.  Building something around an ATtiny84A will be challenging enough (as cautioned above); but intentionally making it even harder by trying to do it without recourse to ISP to iteratively fix mistakes would be the height of masochistic stupidity.

Comment: Thank you guys for your discussion :) You helped me a lot. I am an open source developer the code is not a problem. But hardware is a little one. I will find suitable solution with custom firmware for reading sd card for program or another flash built into chip which can be reprogrammed through AVR. There is a lot of solutions but thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome - but do note that the AVR chips (of which the ATtiny's are an example) cannot execute programs from external memory or RAM - they can only run from their internal flash.  So putting a program on an SD card is only an indirect method of flashing it into the chip.

Comment: Oh yes. That was just an idea. I have no idea how would I get around this problem I was just hoping that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [Surface Mount Adapter Kits](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/l/logical-systems/surface-mount-adapter-kits)

[image]

This is a soldered version for breadboard prototyping.

There is a model that doesn't requires soldering:

[image]

This cost US$70 (http://www.logicalsys.com/painfo-vpasp-vb.asp?adapter=pa8tss-ot)

After that, you mount your SMD on a breadboard and program the ATtiny as normal.

Of course, it doesn't work if your ATtiny is already soldered in the watch.

Comment: Wau. That is expansive. Thank you for the answer :). I was hoping that someone would tell me how to make it programmable if it is in the project via USB. But still thanks :)

Comment: No.  This is unlikely to really help with the problem of the question.  For prototyping one might as well use a DIP if available.  And out-of-circuit programming in that socket won't be viable during software development, as it would mean continuously desoldering chips.  Nor will it be viable for production beyond a handful.  Essentially, the poster needs to set up in circuit serial programming.

Comment: @ChrisStratton. The right way to do it is develop in breadboard, not in the watch itself. Or have a prototype watch with connectors. With that options you can develop and test prototypes in real world. Ugly? Yes, but works. This is an X-Y problem.

Comment: @LookAlterno - you can do preliminary work on a breadboard, but not being able to readily change the firmware while refining the actual fits-on-wrist build **is utterly unacceptable** - and that's what staying within the bounds of your suggestion would lead to.  This isn't in any way an XY problem - a very appropriate question was asked, which you failed to address at all - we might fairly call this an "XY answer".